# Custom Camera Preview Android

Tags: android, android-camera, preview

I'm trying to create a custom camera preview like the one used by WhatsApp. To illustrate the problem, I'm adding an image below:

[Example of Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8CPw.png)

I'm using the following code to open the camera activity:

```
imgCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File(path);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
});
```

And trying the below to show up the preview:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Intent startPreview = new Intent(this.getContext(), PreviewActivity.class);
        startPreview.putExtra("path", path);
        startActivity(startPreview);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

However, it is not showing up my preview custom activity. It is showing the common one.

Could someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't show your activity, because the intent you specify is [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) which states:

> Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera application capture an image and return it.

If you have your custom activity to handle camera capture/preview/etc. you need to call new Intent(Context, YourActivity.class)

Comment: I don't have my own activity to handle camera capture, I want to change the screen after the picture was taken. As the standard show an cancel button or save.

Comment: I would guess you need to create one yourself.

Comment: I was able to add it after accept the picture using the standard, but in that case I will have 2 actions for the same, I will try to find a way to avoid it.